# NSNumber CGFloat value in 64-bit environment

Tags: ios, objective-c, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, nsnumber

What code should I use to get `CGFloat` value from a `NSNumber` variable on 64-bit iOS app?
I am using `-floatValue` right now, but not sure that it is the best way to deal with this.